# How to run a Java Maven project from terminal

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, terminal

I made a Java program using IntelliJ IDEA. It's a Maven project due to I had to add the following dependencies into the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I want to run this program in the terminal but I'm a bit lost on how to do this.

I tried navigating through the project folders:

`cd Project/target/test-classes/`

Then executing this:

`java bot.Main`

But I get the following error:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
> try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Seems like it doesn't take into account the `pom.xml` file and it's dependencies, how can I properly do this?

Project files are the following:

[image]

(Inside `java` folder (green one), there's a package named "bot" and the `Main` class)

Comment: How is the project build? War, Jar?

Comment: The project build is a Jar

Comment: Then you don't need maven to run it, just use `java -jar myfile.jar`